# WITLESS Inscription 5

Tags: puzzle-creation, grid-deduction

2 days ago, TheGreatEscaper had to take down Inscription 5 of [WITLESS - A Puzzling Journey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47870/witless-a-puzzling-journey), due to (can you clarify TheGreatEscaper?) the lack of a solution.

> Can anyone think of a valid Inscription 5 so that TheGreatEscaper can finish their puzzle?

Please don't just post an inscription, put an example solve in spoilers so your inscription can be checked by the community.

Comment: Of course, a valid inscription should cause for a unique partitioning of the 5 grids, and change the partitioning of at least one grid. Ideally, we're changing the partitioning of the 4x4 grid ;)

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure this is too broad.

Comment: @Deusovi I wouldn't necessarily say so, given that TGE hasn't come up with a new inscription there must be a pretty small solution set, if any.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's impossible to figure out what it's asking expect by doing outside research. If someone's willing to do so, and summarize the requirements in the question, that would be good - but as it stands this isn't self-contained

Comment: Eh, I voted to leave open. I don't think "requiring outside research" is a good reason to close a question, imho

Comment: @bobble I assume you mean that this question is asking about a different question on this site, in which case I think it's fine to leave it as it is - the self-containedness policy is mostly used to discourage puzzles that require sources of information that are likely to go missing or be hard to find in the future, and I don't think the information source this question relies on fits either bill (though it wouldn't hurt to put the context in the question anyway)