# The trunk of trivial trials

Tags: reverse-puzzling, humor

<sub>This puzzle is a knockoff of humn's [The case of the world's easiest puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49584/the-case-of-the-world-s-easiest-puzzles). (humn has encouraged spinoffs in a comment.)</sub>

[image]

Hey be careful with that case! Even the slightest nudge, jostle, or jog, and poof, those puzzles are solved. And trust me, not even the most gullible mark, er...

Hello there! Step right up, sir or madam, and witness here in this portable display trunk *more* of the simplest puzzles known to man. Yes, we have here the most frivolous, the most fatuous, the most utterly uninspiring puzzles you've ever seen, and for a mere five dollars—yes, that's right, a mere five dollars each—I'll give you their rules and let you have at them.

Wait, what? You want to solve them without my identifying them for you? Fine, go ahead big shot... But I won't be impressed unless you can also tell me the name of each kind of puzzle...

<sub>(This simple puzzle asks you to identify puzzle types from near-limiting cases of those puzzle types. It is less open-ended and requires much less creativity than its predecessor, but maybe it will teach you about a new type of puzzle.)</sub>

Comment: c. looks like [Sokoban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban)

Comment: a is a maze, g is a nonogram

Comment: h is slitherlink, i is peg solitaire.

Comment: d is a Kakuro; g could be mine-sweeper; h is Slitherlink

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Except where noted, I found all of these without the comments - some may be wrong, though.)

> A. maze
>  B. assembly puzzle
>  C. sokoban
>  D. kakuro
>  E. <s>[Bongard Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bongard_problem)</s> Spot the Difference
>  F. numberlink (aka "Flow Free")
>  G. picross/nonogram
>  H. slitherlink
>  I. [Witless](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47870/witless-a-puzzling-journey) *(Jaap Scherphuis proposes peg solitaire, which sounds much more plausible)*
>  J. Hashiwokakero
>  K. [Stained Glass](http://www.janko.at/Raetsel/Nikoli/Sutendogurasu.htm) *(thanks, Edderiofer!)*

Comment: K is [Stained Glass](http://www.janko.at/Raetsel/Nikoli/Sutendogurasu.htm).

Answer (score 4):

Answers /guesses with solutions and links,
followed by a slosh of backpuzzle.*

> [image]

Links:

> a. [Maze](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mazes)
>  
>  b. [Double Tangoes](http://www.smarttangoesdealer.com/buy/dt200/double-tangoes-case-of-6)
>        (I have a set)
>  
>   c. [reCAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA)
>               (???)
>  
>  d. [Kakuro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakuro)
>  
>  e. [Spot The Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference)
>  
>   f. [Numberlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numberlink)
>  
>  g. [Nonogram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonogram)
>  
>  h. [Slitherlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slitherlink)
>  
>   i. [Odd one out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odd-one-out)
>             (?)
>  
>   j. [Hashiwokakero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashiwokakero)
>  
>  k. [Droodle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droodles)
>       (??)

**Backpuzzle.**
 
To compensate for three woefully wrong simplistic answers above,
see three of the world’s *least simple* puzzles,
on the floor over there,
from the side.

[image]

Obvious what they are?

> [image]

<sub>Footnote:


******* *Backpuzzle*.
 
Noun
([*backwash*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/backwash) + *puzzle*).
 
Puzzling substance that flows back into a post
after a sip of solution.</sub>

Comment: The tags seem to be visible through the spoiler, not sure if you want that.

Comment: I intended it to be a generic tangram, not to scale with the canonical set; Double Tangoes works just as well. Regarding k., a hint: It's a Nikoli puzzle.